# Software Update is offering 14.10

Tags: release-freya, updates

Is this safe to do?

[image: screenshot]

I like to make sure my software is complete, but do not want to ruin the beautiful setup of elementary OS.

Comment: Okay, I will check, and thanks for the replies!

Comment: I got this same thing for 15.10 before

Answer (score 5):

I would check Software & Updates, Updates. Where it says: Notify me of new Ubuntu Version:

Is it set to Never? or something else? Set it to Never.

Comment: I would set it to LTS release only.

Answer (score 4):

I highly doubt that that is from elementary, more like something from Ubuntu. Don't do that, it can and will kill your current elementary OS installation.